# restore Ubuntu's default settings without having to reinstall

Tags: 12.04, configuration, home-directory, restore

I want to restore Ubuntu 12.04 to it's stock configuration, but I don't want to reinstall or reformat my home partition. I don't have a way to backup my files, which is why I don't want to have to reinstall and reformat my hdd.

Is there a way to do this??

Comment: i think there is no way .

Comment: Some components offer a reset option - unity for example. In other cases, there's no other way but to uninstall the package including its config files, and re-install them.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore gnome-related (not you video card, display, x-server, etc.) settings using:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

Here is a link to ubuntu forums which discusses the same: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060406

Comment: Thanks everybody for your input but I found a way to do it on a forum. It consists of reinstalling Ubuntu but keeping my home partition intact. Then logging in as root, creating a new user, moving all the files I want to keep to the new user's home folder. Afterwards I deleted my original homefolder, then renamed the newuser's homefolder with my user name and chown -R it to my username and group. Then I Deleted the new user. And Voilá, my installation was good as new but with all my stuff intact.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore your monitor resolution by:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and reboot.